# Alternative proof of correctness for Floy-Warshall algorithm

Tags: graph-theory

During one of my course's homework I have found myself trying to come up with a different proof of correctness for the Floyd-Warshall algorithm.
However, the feedback was not great although no detailed explanation was given.
Could you help me spot mistakes in my proof?

Let $d$ be the matrix in which each element $d[i,j]$ represents the minimum cost possible for the path $i \rightarrow j$.

Still using induction:

**Base case**: $j = i$. Clearly $d[i,i] = 0$, as no negative-cost cycles are allowed by the algorithm (or at least won't give a proper solution).

**Induction**: $j > i$. By strong induction I can assume $d[i,j]$ correct for any $j \le i$.
The algorithm will loop with indexes $(i,j,k)$ and by the triangular inequality it will check $d[k,j]$ looking for better alternatives. By the strong induction we know that $d[k,j]$ will be correct for any $j \le i$ therefor updating correctly the new entry in the matrix.
By using mutual induction on $i$ the proof can be extended for the $d[k,j]$ access in the previous step, therefore completing our proof of correctness.

Any hint would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: It would help if you explicitly wrote down the statement you are trying to prove by induction. It also seems that in your "induction" step $j$ is overloaded: you start by writing $j > i$, but then write "for any $j \leq i$".